# While copying txt files from one folder to another giving error using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to copy the files from one folder to another folder its giving error that its being used by another process.But it dint open any where.These are txt files.

Error : The process cannot access the file 'D:\Vimal\test1\test2.txt' because it is being used by another process.

```
Sub MoveFile()
    Dim _sSourcePath As String = "D:\Vimal\test1"
    Dim _sDesPath As String = "D:\Vimal\test2"
    Dim _FilelstSource As New DirectoryInfo(_sSourcePath)
    Dim _FilelstDest As New DirectoryInfo(_sDesPath)
    Dim list1 = _FilelstSource.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim list2 = _FilelstDest.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim _sTempstr As String = String.Empty
    _sTempstr = "ProcessDldFiles"
    Dim myFileCompare As New FileCompare

    Try

        If list1.Count > 0 Then
            Dim _queryDiff = list1.Except(list2, myFileCompare)
            If _queryDiff.ToList.Count > 0 Then
                For Each filename As FileInfo In _queryDiff
                    ' File.Copy(filename.FullName, filename.FullName.Replace("BAMDailyFile", _sTempstr), True)
                    File.Copy(filename.FullName, Path.Combine(_sDesPath, filename.Name), True)
                Next
                ' WriteDesLog("Total No. old cases file " & Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & ":" & _queryDiff.ToList.Count())
            Else
                ' WriteDesLog("No Case to Download due to difference " & Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' InsertErrorLog("CompareFilesToProcess", "", ex.ToString(), Date.Now.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

Public Class FileCompare
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of FileInfo)

Public Function Equals1(ByVal x As FileInfo, ByVal y As FileInfo) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of FileInfo).Equals

        If (x.Name = y.Name) And (x.Length = y.Length) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

Public Function GetHashCode1(ByVal fi As FileInfo) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of FileInfo).GetHashCode
        Dim s As String = fi.Name & fi.Length
        Return s.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Perhaps you have created this file someplace else in your program and not closed the stream to it?

Comment: @Magnus : thanks for revert.no its on same path.by the way i found the solution.

Comment: @vim If you change the question to have the correct code, then we can't easily see what the problem was, and also your answer then makes no sense.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : you are very correct. I will update as per your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change the line for File.Copy

File.Copy(filename.FullName, Path.Combine(_sDesPath, filename.Name), True)